# Скрипт Python сохраняет только последнюю строку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть вот такой вот скрипт:

```
import json


while True:
    print("1. Добавить новую запись")
    print("2. Поиск по записям")
    print("0. выйти из программы")
    cmd = input("Выберите пункт: ")


if cmd == "1":
  print ("Ввод данных")

  allowed_characters= ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']

  data = {"Введите ID": input ()}
  if any(x not in allowed_characters for x in data):
        print("error: Ввод только цифр")
       

  print ("Введите ФИО")

  data = {"Name": input ()}

  print ("Введите email")
  
  data = {"Email": input ()}

  print ("Введите номер телефона")

  data = {"Phone": input ()}
  

  with open("users.json", "a+", encoding="utf-8") as file:
           file.write('\n')
           json.dump(data, file, ensure_ascii=False)


elif cmd == "2":
       print ("Введите данные для поиска")
       w = input()
       with open("Users.json") as fin:
           for s in fin.readlines():
              if s.find(w) > -1:
                print(s.strip())


elif cmd == "0":
                break
```

Проблема в следующем - сохраняет в файл только последнюю строку - Phone, при этом каких либо ошибок не выдает. При этом изначально, когда писался только блок ввода данных скрипт отрабатывал как надо, этот блок не изменялся.

Кто может подсказать в какую сторону смотреть?

Python 3.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом блоке кода вы каждый раз заново пересоздаете словарь `data`, вместо того, чтобы добавлять в него значения

```
print ("Введите ФИО")
data = {"Name": input ()}
print ("Введите email")
data = {"Email": input ()}
print ("Введите номер телефона")
data = {"Phone": input ()}
```

Правильно будет добавлять значения так *(можно еще упростить код, добавив аргумент `print()` в `input()`)*:

```
data = {"Name": input("Введите ФИО\n")}
data["Email"] = input("Введите email\n")
data["Phone"] = input("Введите номер телефона\n")
```

Подробнее про словари можно почитать [**здесь**](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/slovari-dict-funkcii-i-metody-slovarej.html)

Comment: Большое спасибо, это решило проблему.  За ссылочку тоже спасибо, полезная информация.

Comment: @НикитаКовалев если вопрос закрыт, то могу я попросить вас пометить его как решение? :)

Comment: Не сразу разобрался, пометил, ещё раз спасибо и хорошего дня)